# changing select menu and assign input value

Tags: jquery, html

I have a drop down list and is trying to assign specific values when onclick on any < option > I currently have the code below but it's not working. not sure what I am missing.

Jquery Code:

```
{literal}
<script>    
$(function() {
var values = {
    "pop": 110,
    "spop": 995,
    "imap": 113,
    "simap": 993,
    "default": 000
};

window.connection_type = function(val) {
    var port = values[val] || values["default"];        
    $('input[name="port_no"]').val(port);
}
});
</script>
{/literal}
```

Drop down List.

```
<select class="selmenu selmenu-200" name="type" onChange="connection_type(this.value)">
<option value="pop">POP</option>
<option value="spop">Secure POP</option>
<option value="imap">IMAP</option>
<option value="simap">Secure IMAP</option>
</select> 

<input type="text" name="port_no" value="" />
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: If you copy the code verbatim into a jsfiddle and load jquery(1.9.1) it works...there may be something else wrong. Are you getting any errors in the console? Or maybe provide a fiddle of your own with the problem in question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**js**

```
window.connection_type = function(val)
{
    var newValue="";
    switch(val) {
    case "pop":
        newValue = 110;
        break;
    case "spop":
        newValue = 995;
        break;
       //rest cases you probably want         
    }

    $('input[name="port_no"]').val(newValue);       
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22dJE/5/)

html js solution, if you want to place a custom attribute in your option element:

**html**

```
<select class="selmenu selmenu-200" name="type" onChange="connection_type(this)">
<option value="pop" specVal="110">POP</option>
<option value="spop" specVal="995">Secure POP</option>
<option value="imap">IMAP</option>
<option value="simap">Secure IMAP</option>
</select> 

<input type="text" name="port_no" value="" id="txtPort" />
```

**js**

```
window.connection_type = function(val)
{   
   $("#txtPort").val($(val).find("option:selected").attr("specVal"));      
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22dJE/18/)

Comment: hi Alek, thanks for your help, but for some reason I cannot get this to work. I update my question with ur recommendation.

Comment: Test my second approach please. Btw both of them work :)

Comment: Thanks alex, testing now. will let you know in a few

Comment: ur second approach is not working in fiddle though :(

Comment: thanks for the help guys, I am still having issues and not sure why this is not working for me, it works well in the fiddle. I will try to diagnose my script. no error in console :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of the default operator `||`. You can make an object that holds all the possibilities:

```
var values = {
    "pop": 110,
    "spop": 995,
    "imap": 113,
    "simap": 993,
    "default": 000
};
```

and check it against whats input from the dom with default:

```
var port = values[val] || values["default"];        
$('input[name="port_no"]').val(port);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/def9a/2/)

Comment: Hi Ruce, same here, I tried it but it's not working for me. I am currently using jquery 1.9

Comment: *Bruce :P and I switched the fiddle to 1.9.1 and it works... http://jsfiddle.net/def9a/3/